# Can my contacts know if I'm on another call when they try to call me

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Will they know if I'm at another call even if it's not using the whats up app? On a regular cell call it would just keep ringing if the person is on another call. If you have call waiting you know they're calling you. I don't know if I explained myself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your service provider.

In my country, all the networks will inform the caller that you are on another call via automated response; they will be asked to either hold on or call you back.

Hope this answers your question.